# python inspect.getargspect

Tags: python, module, inspect

Imports a module and then goes through the module's namespace to find any functions (you may assume any object with a **call**() method is a function) and print the names of the functions and their arguments, in the same way as it might appear in a  def statement.

My problem is after I have loop through the module and gotten all the function I can not pass the function name to inspect.getfullargspec() because it is a string.How do i make the string callable?

```
import inspect
from smtplib import SMTP
from pprint import pprint
def func(x):     
    for item in inspect.getmembers(x):
         lst = inspect.getmembers(x, inspect.isfunction)
         for items in lst:
              func_names = items[0] #names of functions               
              f = r"%s.%s" % (x.__name__, func_names)
              arg = inspect.getargspec(f)
              print(f)



if __name__ == '__main__':
     func(SMTP)
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a few mistakes in this. The quick answer, though, is that that you don't want to make string callable, you just need to know that `inspect.getmembers` returns a list of `('func_name', <function object>)` pairs, and `inspect.getargspec` expects a function object.

So you could make your for-loop look like this:

```
for name, fun in lst:
    long_name = r"%s.%s" % (x.__name__, name)
    argspec = inspect.getargspec(fun)
    print(long_name)
```

As a separate issue, you rvariable names are mostly nondescriptive and occasionally incorrect. For example, what you call `func_names` is always exactly *one* name, and the variable `lst` would be more usefully named `members`, and `item` should be `member`. Naming a function `func` is not normally good practice, especially when that function needs several variables inside of that should also, more appropriately, be named `func`.

Comment: Even better, make the for loop do the assignment for you:

    `for name, func in lst:`

Comment: @Matthew: I don't know what I was thinking :-)

Answer (score 0):

lst here is a tuple of function name and function object, you do not really need to do all the string manipulation. Below simple method will do the job:

```
def func(module):
    for lst in inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isfunction):
        if inspect.isfunction(lst[1]):# Doing an additional check, may not be actually required
            print(lst[0]+inspect.formatargspec(*inspect.getfullargspec(lst[1])))
```